# Reading special UTF-8 characters from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

How can I read special characters from a ByteBuffer? `ByteBuffer.wrap("\u0001".getBytes()).asCharBuffer().get()` throws a `BufferUnderflow` exception. As far as I understand `ByteBuffer.getChar()` always advances by two bytes, and there's only one byte in this string.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to iterate over UTF-8 encoded characters in a ByteBuffer without going via String?

Comment: If you’re certain the ByteBuffer contains UTF-8-encoded characters, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString()`.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, I want avoid heap allocations as much as possible

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in functionality for reading a single UTF-8 encoded code point from a ByteBuffer, so you'd have to write your own.

Comment: Why aren't you using `CharBuffer.wrap()`? Eliminate all the round-trips?